# Hibernate foreign key as part of primary key

Tags: hibernate, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

I have to work with hibernate and not very sure how solve this problem, I've 2 table with a 1..n relationship like this:

```
-------
TABLE_A
-------
first_id (pk)
second_id (pk)
[other fields]

-------
TABLE_B
-------
first_id (pk)(fk TABLE_A.first_id)
second_id (pk)(fk TABLE_A.second_id)
third_id (pk)
[other fields]
```

How can I manage this with Hibernate???

I don't have idea how to manage the primary key for the second table...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is an example which is completely similar to your case in the [Hibernate reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e4865). Just before this example, you'll find the explanations. Here's the example, which matches your problem (User is table A, and Customer is table B):

```
@Entity
class Customer {
   @EmbeddedId CustomerId id;
   boolean preferredCustomer;

   @MapsId("userId")
   @JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name="userfirstname_fk", referencedColumnName="firstName"),
      @JoinColumn(name="userlastname_fk", referencedColumnName="lastName")
   })
   @OneToOne User user;
}

@Embeddable
class CustomerId implements Serializable {
   UserId userId;
   String customerNumber;

   //implements equals and hashCode
}

@Entity 
class User {
   @EmbeddedId UserId id;
   Integer age;
}

@Embeddable
class UserId implements Serializable {
   String firstName;
   String lastName;

   //implements equals and hashCode
}
```

Note: it would be much much simpler of you had a surrogate identifier for those two tables. Unless you're forced to deal with a legacy schema, do yourself a favor and use surrogate keys.

Comment: But do you know if there are some problems if I change instead of put the OneToOne annotation on the Customer, put a OneToMany on the User class???

Comment: You'll have to make it a bidirectional OneToMany/ManyToOne association.

Comment: Doing so, I get `Attribute "userId" has invalid mapping in this context` inside of `CustomerId`

Answer (score 4):

Use `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` and `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns` annotations. From [Hibernate manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association):

> The `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` annotation does say that the primary key of the entity is used as the foreign key value to the associated entity.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question: he has a composite primary key, and some of the fields of this composite primary key constitute a foreign key to another entity. @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn is used when a primary key is also a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5478661842746845130L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
}
@Entity
public class Author {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "AUTHOR_ID", nullable = false)
    private int authorId;
    @Column(name = "ENABLED", nullable = false, length = 1)
    private boolean enabled;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "AUTHOR_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    User user;

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

Comment: My problem was little bit different, in my case the `User` entity has `username` and `email` as PK (so I can have the same username associated to different email) and `Author` having the same PK as `User` (`username`, `email`) and also `vatCode`, not just an `id` as in your example ;)

Answer (score 0):

For Table A you can make you of embeddedId

```
@Emebddable
class PrimaryKeyIdTableA{
 private Integer firstId,

 private Integer secondId
}


class A {
 @EmebddedId
 private PrimaryKeyIdTableA id
}
```

For Table B you can use Idclass also as shown below

```
Class PrimaryKeyIdTableB {

private PrimaryKeyIdTableA id,

private Integer thirdId

 }

 @Idclass(PrimaryKeyIdTableB.class)
 Class TableB{
 @Id
 private Integer thirdId,
 
  @Id
  @onetoone
  @Joincolumns({
  @Joincolumn(name=firstid),
  @Joincolumn(name=secondId)})
 private PrimaryKeyIdTableA id
    }
```