# Create two primary key (Also those are foreign key) from different class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

```
class A{
@id
int a;
}

enter code here

class B {
@id
int b;
}
```

A

a ====> primary key

B

b ====> primary key

C

a and b needs to be primary key for the table. Also a and b are foreign key

How to add a and b into the third table(C) as a primary key which also needs to be foreign key too?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@EmbeddedId` with `@MapsId` on to-one associations.

Examples can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31389630/4754790), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146671/hibernate-foreign-key-as-part-of-primary-key) and in the [official documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e4865).